# the function of pointer NULL in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class A {
public:
    int value = 1;
    void foo() { ... };
};

int main() {
A *a = NULL;
int temp = a->value;   // Crash!
a->foo();              // OK
}
```

What happened after I assigned the pointer NULL to a pointer variable? I thought nothing can be done until I allocate a memory to it by new. However, it still can call member function foo(), but crashed when calling member variable.

Could anyone tell me what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Your code has a bug, so of course it doesn't do what you expect. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. This is why we fix bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both invoke Undefined Behavior, irrespective of the behavior you're observing, *because* when it is UB, *anything* is possible.

However, one explanation why it does't crash in the second case, possibly because the call:

```
nullptr->foo(); //a == nullptr, becomes implicit 'this' inside foo()
```

is translated to:

```
foo(nullptr);   //the implicit 'this' passed as first argument
```

by the compiler, which seems fine (to the compiler), as you're not  accessing any member data inside the function. If you access member data, the chance of getting it crashed increases.  The compiler is just being tolerant of your wrongful deeds as long as it can.

Answer (score 3):

de-referencing NULL pointer is undefined behavior. You are unlucky that you got through it in second statement.

In this case, it appears to work because the `this pointer`, which does not point to a valid object, is not used in `foo` .If it happened to refer to `this` there would have been one less post on stack overflow.